# Customising segmented control with two labels

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am looking to customise the uisegmented control as shown in figure.Help or links will be of great help[image]

Answer (score 3):

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=Segment

Try It following link. I think it should work.

or if you have only 3 buttons then you create 3 buttons and you can add two labels on a button programmatically

Comment: i would go with three views with tap gesture recognizer added

Comment: Great but i think the best way is to add two labels as a subview of UIButton.You can add labels in UIButton because UIButton is also subclass of uiview

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `UISegementControl` you can customise this by the `UICollectionView`by enabling the `pageControl` property. Or use this cocoa pod from [here](https://github.com/Yalantis/Segmentio)